# Multilingual LTR to RTL

Tags: php, css, wordpress, multilingual

Hi I am creating a multilingual website on WordPress,and currently working on the CSS for the RTL language, I am facing the below issue.

Across the site I have custom headings (H2, H3, H4)

- In the LTR some of them are aligned center, and others are aligned left.
- NOW in RTL language, when I overwrite the CSS with the below:

  `html[lang="ar"] H4 {direction: RTL!important; text-align: right!important;}`

What happens that all H4 headings across the site aligns to the right.

What I need to do is that only the headings that are aligned left in the LTR are to be aligned right in the RTL. And what is aligned center to remain aligned center.

Can you advise how to modify the above code, to do so Or what is the alternative solution?

Comment: Maybe in CSS if it is a PHP file, do `text-align: <?= $align ?>` and in a main PHP file assign `center`, `right` or `left` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define 3 classes (`.align-right`, `.align-left` and `.align-center`) for alignments:

```
/* For LTR language (default) */
.align-right {
   text-align: right;
}
.align-left {
   text-align: left;
}
.align-center {
   text-align: center;
}

/* For RTL language */
html[lang="ar"] .align-right {
   text-align: left;
}
html[lang="ar"] .align-left {
   text-align: right;
}
```

then use this classes for each heading tag or any other elements.